# Search function issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I am trying to create a program that allows a user to search poverty data from a specific county in South Carolina. The program uses a dictionary `county` that is appended to a list `counties`. The issue arises here:

```
def search_counties(counties):
search = input('Search: ')
search = search.lower()
while search != 'q' or search != 'quit':
    if search == 'q' or search == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif search != 'q' or search != 'quit':
        for i in counties:
            if search in counties:
                print_county(county)
            elif search not in counties:
                search = input("Search: ")
                search = search.lower()
```

However, the current issue is that it will not evaluate the search at all. Instead it constantly prompts for a new search, and even entering 'quit' or 'q' does not end it:

```
Search: 
Search:
Search:
```

I am only asking this after searching through every source I can find for hours. How can I make it properly evaluate the search?

Comment: you indendation is wrong, it does not work like that. Paste your real code instead.

Comment: @staz have you already tried my solution? If it helped, you could mark it as solved  

Comment: It is still prompting for search constantly, I implemented it with .values, .items, and .keys

Comment: What have you tried to pass as a search query? Let's suppose that `county = {'some1': 'a', 'some2': 'b'}`. In case of just `search in county` (which is equal to `search in county.keys()`)  you may pass `some1` or `some2`. In case of `search in county.values()` you should pass `a` or `b`.

Comment: I have tried using _Horry_, _Cobb_, and _Georgetown_.  County looks like this `county = {"count":int(child_count),"poverty":float(percent),"median":int(median),"county":county_name}` if it helps more.

Comment: So, you want to search it by name?

Comment: Right, then it will go to another function.

Comment: @staz then check out the updated answer, it should solve your issue

Comment: That last one worked, thank you so much for all your help!!

Comment: @staz you're welcome, don't forget to mark it as solved (so that the green tick appeared on the answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to search an input string in a list of dictionaries:

```
if search in counties:
    print_county(county)
```

It will always return false therefore will be asked for the next input. It seems to me that you wanted something like this:

```
def search_counties(counties):
    county_names = [c.county.lower() for c in counties]

    while True:
        search = input('Search: ').lower()
        if search in ('q' ,'quit'):
            sys.exit()

        if search in county_names:
            print_county(county)
```

**Update:**

Updated the code considering you `county` structure as:

```
{
    "count": int(child_count),
    "poverty": float(percent),
    "median": int(median),
    "county": county_name
}
```